# Visual Studio 2013 - which edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

We are currently using VS 2010 professional edition and I am keen to move to 2013. I am concerned that if my company gets professional again we may not get features that we need. 
In particular, I want to:

- Use the Bundling and Minification tools available in .Net 4.5 for JavaScript and CSS
- Access the test explorer using the Chutzpah test adapter (to test javascript)

I've looked at the comparison between different VS 2013 but it's not clear (to me!) whether or not these options will be available. Will these be available in Visual Studio 2013 Professional?

Obviously there are many benefits to 2013 but the above two are the features that may persuade my company to purchase a different (more expensive) edition if required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013 Comparison Chart:
https://softsale.co.il/Content/Images/uploaded/VS2013%20Compare%20Versions.pdf